# Dates not visible in FFCalendar in iOS 9

Tags: ios, calendar, ios9, icalendar, nscalendar

Dates are not visible in FFCalander iOS 9 ,but every thing is working fine in iOS 8 .I changed all the deprecated methods then also facing the same problem.
Can anyone help.

[image]

Thanks and regards,
Ranbijay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution from github

In FFMonthCell.m

`- (void)initLayout {
...
labelDay = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((imageViewCircle.frame.size.width-25.)/2., (imageViewCircle.frame.size.height-25.)/2., 25., 25.)];
}`

Thanks.